# Acquire string from user and then delete it from screen

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, scanf

This simple program acquires characters from the users (till a newline character) and prints them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char local_message[200];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", local_message);
    printf("Your message is %s\n", local_message);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, the characters I typed stay printed into the screen:

```
Hello World!
Your message is Hello World!
```

The characters I typed were "Hello World!\n". I would like that when I press "Enter" to create the newline `\n` character, my message disappears from the screen (while being stored into the `char` array), so that I can print (and format) it with the following `printf`.

The OS is Linux.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @CoolGuy a *nix OS, Linux

Comment: You can use `ncurses`.

Comment: @Olaf it is not strictly necessary, but aren't there solutions which are not bound to a OS library? For example, some internal C library

Comment: Feel free to find one: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7. Just ask yourself: Which side (OS or StdLib) is responsible for console control?

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to do this with terminal escape codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
    char local_message[200];

    scanf("%199[^\n]%*c", local_message);
    printf ( "\033[0A");//move cursor up one line
    printf ( "\033[2K");//clear line
    printf("\nYour message is %s\n", local_message);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
This will give a little more control and erase inputs more than one line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
    char local_message[200];

    printf ( "\033[2J");//clear screen and move cursor to upper left corner
    printf ( "\033[8;H");//move cursor to line 8
    printf("Enter Your message\n");
    scanf("%199[^\n]%*c", local_message);
    printf ( "\033[9;H");//move cursor to line 9
    printf ( "\033[J");//clear screen from line to end
    printf ( "\033[12;H");//move cursor to line 12
    printf("\nYour message is %s\n", local_message);

    return 0;
}
```